# New files (.sql) on database project not added to tfs automatically

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2017, database-project

Unlike the other projects, new files in the database project (.sqlproj) are not available while trying to check-in from solution explorer. I can able to see the changed files but not new files.

Every time I add new files, I need to go to Source control explorer and look for "Add Items to folder" option.

It messes when there are few changed files and few added files. We will check-in from solution explorer and after some time the production team will curse us for not including the files.

Anyone facing the same? Do I miss anything?

Comment: How and where did you generate the new files? Have the projects been added in source control?

Comment: I'm adding new files through schema compare and sometimes Add -> New Item options.

Comment: whatever you need to make sure the project already in source control and the new files generated within the workspace, otherwise they will not be identified automatically.